# how different display of two condition with php and css

Tags: php, css, icons

I try to use google to find a solution for my question but nothing good, 
I have a table `accounts_` with a column `condition_` , I display dynamically all rows in `<table>`

In column `condition_`  I have two condition the account is **active**  or **incative**   what I want is to display an icon inactive if it's inactive and an icon active if it's active.

Help, thanks

Comment: sounds like a job for a simple `if\else`

Comment: Can you show us your existing code so we can use that to help?

Comment: easy way  `if\else` Thanks @Dagon,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not write your code so only i can guess your code to answer your question

```
$yourdata["db"];
foreach ($yourdata["db"] as $key => $value)  {
if($value["condition_"]=="active")
$statu='<img src="">'; // your active img url
elseif($value["condition_"]=="incative")
$statu='<img src="">'; // your incative img url
}
```

in your table

```
echo '
<tr>
<th>'.$statu.'</th>
</tr>';
```

you can show your img by this method